# System design pattern for recurring payments

Tags: design-patterns

I'd like to ask what are some common, widely adopted patterns to design a system which auto-renew user's subscription when it expires.

I'm specifically asking how to trigger that operation?

Assume there's a system, with some RenewSubscription method that do the all logic. The method should be triggered just after user's subscription expired.

The only way I see to implement it is to have some kind of background task (console app or lambda) that query DB every N seconds (or minutes) and checks if there is any expired subscription to renew.

Can this be implemented without querying DB every few seconds?

Answer (score 1):

It would be necessary to query the database at some point to fetch the users with expired subscription, so in any case some kind of cron job is needed. As for how often the background task should be triggered IMO it depends on what's your acceptable threshold between expiration and renewal (seconds, minutes, hours). Also take in account the performance of the RenewSubscription method, the amount of users to update and the time it takes to run the database query. Ideally the cron job should finish before the next one starts and if that's not possible you need to take in account how many processes could be running in parallel without hitting memory/CPU bounds if any. I believe you'll have to run some benchmarks to find an acceptable balance for your use case.